# Syntax error while defining an array as a property of a class

Tags: php, object

```
...

public $aSettings = array(
  'BindHost' => "127.0.0.1",
  'Port' => 9123,
  'MaxFileSize' => (5 * (1024 * 1024)), // unexpected "(" here
  'UploadedURL' => "http://localhost",
  'UploadPath' => dirname(__FILE__) . "/upload",
  'UploadMap' => dirname(__FILE__) . "/uploads.object",
  'RegisterMode' => false
);

...
```

This is my code, straight from a class. The problem I have is the `"unexpected ( on line 22"`, line 22 being `MaxFileSize`.

I can't see a problem with it, is this a Zend Engine limitation? Or am I blind.

Comment: Works fine for me -> http://codepad.org/EIorteTQ  .... im guessing its a problem defining non-constant variable in a class

Comment: Have you tried to just remove the outer `( )`? Or just all `( )` on that line, as there is no need for them when doing multiplication...

Comment: I removed the access specifier public and it works

Comment: [silly's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9633940/1941213) to a similar question is useful in this regard. While it uses the same approach as [Michael Krelin's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9225689), it shows a way to include the initialization logic within the class definition.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot use *non-constant values* while initializing class properties in PHP versions earlier than 5.6.
These are initialized at compile time, at which PHP will do no calculations or execute any code. `(5 * (1024 * 1024))` is an expression that requires evaluation, which you cannot do there. Either replace that with the constant value `5242880` or do the calculation in `__construct`.

PHP 5.6, introduced in 2014, [allows "constant scalar expressions"](http://php.net/manual/en/migration56.new-features.php) wherein a scalar constant or class property can be initialized by an evaluated expression in the class definition rather than the constructor.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of that. I'll move the operations to my construct.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect this is not the whole code and this is a definition of a static variable inside a class, where you're quite limited in expressions and can't calculate a lot.

If I'm right, you may want to do something like that instead:

```
class thingamajig {
    public static $aSettings;
};
thingamajig::$aSettings = array ( ... );
```

P.S. Sorry, I've just read your prose where you confirm it's a part of a class static variable. So you can't just ignore out-of-place keyword.

Comment: Indeed it is not all of the code, it was taken from a class file, I removed the surrounding code.

Comment: Yeah, read that now. At first it was too obvious to finish reading :)

Answer (score 3):

I assume what you're showing is actually a class property (because of the public keyword). Initialization of class properties in PHP must be constant.

> This declaration may include an initialization, but this
>   initialization must be a constant value--that is, it must be able to
>   be evaluated at compile time and must not depend on run-time
>   information in order to be evaluated.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php

Answer (score 1):

When you define variable in class, you cannot assign expression to it. `(5 * (1024 * 1024))` is an expression. `6164480` is not.

Comment: Technically `6164480` is an *expression* as well, just a very simple one. :o)

Comment: Hmm... Yep, @deceze described it a lot more accurate :)

Answer (score 0):

### This limitation no longer exists as of PHP 5.6

The new feature that enables the previously-disallowed syntax is called [*constant scalar expressions*](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/migration56.new-features.php#migration56.new-features.const-scalar-exprs):

> It is now possible to provide a scalar expression involving numeric
>   and string literals and/or constants in contexts where PHP previously
>   expected a static value, such as constant and property declarations
>   and default function arguments.
>
> ```
> class C {
>     const THREE = TWO + 1;
>     const ONE_THIRD = ONE / self::THREE;
>     const SENTENCE = 'The value of THREE is '.self::THREE;
>
>     public function f($a = ONE + self::THREE) {
>         return $a;
>     }
> }
>
> echo (new C)->f()."\n"; echo C::SENTENCE; ?>
> ```
>
> The above example will output:
>
> ```
> 4 The value of THREE is 3
> ```

Answer (score -3):

Public is a declaration only used in objects.  This is not an object, remove public and it's fine.

Comment: The code was taken FROM an object, hence ignore the public keyword.

Comment: OK, well I did take it out and php -l came back with no errors, so the error is elsewhere even though it's reporting there.