# Call a method inside an array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, class

I want to call a method inside an array (in a class) in PHP :

```
const emtpy= "Please correct %s";
...
$myArray= array(
    '1'=>'myvalue',
    '2'=> printf(self::emtpy,'user')
);
```

However, Eclipse returns an error for the first bracket of the called method.

```
syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting ')
```

Has someone any ideas ?
Thank you !

Comment: possible duplicate of [(Supposedly) simple PHP syntax error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9225632/supposedly-simple-php-syntax-error)

Answer (score 2):

You cant use expressions like that when defining class members - they need to be static values. If you need to assign defaults based on constants, functions, etc. then you need to do that in the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [anonymous functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) (they are available just since php 5.3.0), but example of what you need is:

```
$myArray = array(
    '1' => 'myvalue',
    '2' => function(){printf( class_name::empty, 'user'); }
);
```

You should rather use [callback](http://php.net/manual/en/language.pseudo-types.php#language.types.callback) whenever possible:

```
$myArray = array(
    '1' => 'myvalue',
    '2' => array( $this, 'myCallback')
);
```

Comment: Thank you.My php version is  5.3.8 but it sound like a cannot use anonymous functions. --syntax error, unexpected 'function' (I have tried with your code)

Answer (score 1):

you could try using array_map.

try out this class:

```
class CallbackArrayClass {

  public static $empty;

  public static function callback($a) {
    self::$empty =  printf("please enter your name %s", $a);
  }

  public function initArray() {
    $myArray= array(
      '1'=>'myvalue',
      '2'=> array_map("self::callback", array('user'))
    );
  }

}

$c = new CallBackArrayClass();
$c->initArray();
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php

```
function callback($a) {
  return printf("please enter your name %s", $a);
}

$myArray= array(
    '1'=>'myvalue',
    '2'=> array_map('callback', array('user'))
);
```

Comment: I have tried with your code, but....-syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting ')'- :-(

Comment: i will quickly write a class and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use a constant like that for the format string for `printf()`.  Try it without the const... make that `emtpy` (spelling) const a $variable.

EDIT:

Here is what I meant... though, the callback idea is not a bad idea.

```
$empty = "Please correct %";

$myArray = array(
  '1' => 'myvalue',
  '2' => printf($empty, 'user')
);

echo $myArray[2];
```

Comment: I think error is not from the const. I have to use an anonymous function, but it does not work.

Comment: Have you tried putting in a regular scalar variable instead of the const, just to check?  I tried it in some dummy code... and it seemed to take away the error on my test, at least.  @prodigitalson has some good advice, below, as well about constructors.

Comment: I tried with ` 'message' => function(){printf( 'Please correct %s', 'user');},` just to check, but error is still here... Thank you for helping me ~

Comment: No problem; I guess what I meant was... have you tried taking out the `const` keyword, and just making `$emtpy` a regular variable?

Comment: I took out the const and use a regular variable for "empty" but problem persists...[syntax error, unexpected 'function'] doesn't disappear.

Comment: I edited my code example above... does something like that work for you?  It worked in my test, at least.