# php same class object into two functions of another class

Tags: php, class

How can I set a public variable class for use into more than one functions?
The code below returns me the following error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_NEW in ...

```
class A {

  var $classB = new B();

  public function __Construct($param1){
    echo $this->classB->export($param1);
  }

  public function otherParam($param2){
    echo $this->classB->export($param2);
  }

}
```

Comment: What kind of error where

Comment: duplicate of [Syntax error while defining an array as a property of a class](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9225632/476)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot instance objects like java. PHP doesn't allow you to initialize your variables to anything but strings or integers (and some really basic stuff).

You will have to use

```
private $classB;
```

and

```
public function __construct($param1){
    $this->classB = new B();
    echo $this->classB->export($param1);
}
```

inside of the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

`$classB` would be a local variabile in your code, and this it is not set.

You want to use `$this -> classB`.

Anyways you would like to inject an instance of `B` inside `A`, consider reading about dependency injection.